# Kivy TypeError - Label object is not callable in Try/Except clause

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

So I'm attempting to create a try/except block to run this code, where they should be able to click out of the popup which prints their answers, and then press the calculate button to reopen it. However, when I go to press the calculate button a second time, it gives me

```
TypeError: 'Label' object is not callable
```

I'll put the code below:

```
class TabSys(TabbedPanel):
savedfiles_hydraulus = []
def calculate_psc_clicked(self, Cp_text, P_text, lhv_text):
    global psychrometric_constant
    #when they click the button which is id'd as "calculate_psc," this function
    #will pull the values and perform the calculations
    try:
        psychrometric_constant = (float(Cp_text)*float(P_text))/(float(lhv_text)*float(2.26))
        self.psc_answer()
    except ValueError:
        """Needs a popup for wrong results"""


#the popups print out the answers and offer the user an option to save or dismiss the window
def psc_answer(self):
    global Flag
    Flag = False

    #Layout
    popupscreen = FloatLayout()
    self.psc_notes_label = Label(text = "Psychrometric constant: (Cp*P)/(λ*MWr)", pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.7})
    self.psc_answer = Label(text = str(psychrometric_constant), pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.4})
    popupscreen.add_widget(self.psc_notes_label)
    popupscreen.add_widget(self.psc_answer)

    #Dismiss Window
    self.cancel_psc_answer = Button(text = "Cancel", pos_hint = {"center_x": .575, "center_y": .065}, size_hint = (.3, .2))
    self.cancel_psc_answer.bind(on_release = self.dismisspsc)
    popupscreen.add_widget(self.cancel_psc_answer)

    #Window Setup
    self.popup = Popup(title="Result", content = popupscreen,  size_hint=(.5, .5), size=(400, 400),
    separator_color = [217/255, 179/255, 255/255., .85])
    self.popup.open()

#Dismiss Function
def dismisspsc(self, *args):
    self.popup.dismiss()
```

It's quite a lot, unfortunately, but I've cut as much out as I could. I can link a pastebin with the entirety of the code as I have it now if anybody needs.

I think the problem might be that the line

```
try:
    psychrometric_constant = (float(CP_text)*float(P_text))/(float(lhv_text)*float(2.26))
```

is in the try/except block, where it might better serve inside the function of psc_answer.

Thanks very much :)

Comment: here's the entirety of my code: https://pastebin.com/p2eCdPRX

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer! If anybody is having this issue it's probably because you've used the same name for the uncallable object as you have for a function at some point. I've named the function psc_answer and the label psc_answer.